# Can $AB-BA=I$ hold if $A$ and $B$ are bounded linear operators on a Banach space?

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

It's easy to see it can't be true in finite dimension. Also, it can hold for operators on infinite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb C$, as seen here: [Can $AB-BA=I$ hold if both $A$ and $B$ are operators on an infinitely-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417007/can-ab-ba-i-hold-if-both-a-and-b-are-operators-on-an-infinitely-dimensiona). What happens if both $A$ and $B$ are bounded linear operators on a Banach space?

Comment: the point is that it cannot happen for continuous or, equivalently, bounded linear operators.

Comment: what's wrong with the example in the answer of the link you gave in the question?

Comment: You can find very nice answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54397/the-identity-cannot-be-a-commutator-in-a-banach-algebra